# If $X_1$ and $X_1 + X_2$ are not independent but $X_1$ and $X_2$ are, can we write $P(X_1=j;X_1+X_2=k)=P(X_1=j)P(X_2=k-j)$

Tags: probability, independence, poisson-distribution

Let say that $X_1,\dots ,X_m$ are independent random variables following Poisson law of parameter $λ_1,\dots, λ_m$.

I want to calculate the probability $P(X_i=j|X_1+X_2=k)$

\begin{align*}
P(X_1=j|X_1+X_2=k)=\frac{P(X_1=j;X_1+X_2=k)}{P(X_1+X_2=k)}
\end{align*}

As far as $X_1$ and $X_1 + X_2$ are not independent but $X_1$ and $X_2$ are, can we write:

\begin{align*}
P(X_i=j|X_1+X_2=k)=\frac{P(X_1=j)P(X_2=k-j)}{P(X_1+X_2=k)}?
\end{align*}

Then it would end as:

\begin{align*}
P(X_i=j|X_1+X_2=k)=\frac{\lambda_1^j\lambda_2^{k-j}}{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^{k-j}}?
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, we can! (where did I hear that before?). Index $i$ should be changed into $1$ though.

Comment: The event $\{X_1=j, X_1+X_2=k\}$ is the same as the event $\{X_1=j,X_2=k-k\}$ (regardless of any independence).

Comment: @JohnDawkins ha? why?

Comment: @Marine1 Because $X_1=j\wedge X_1+X_2=k\iff X_1=j\wedge X_2=k-j$ (it is beyond doubt that John meant to write $k-j$ instead of $k-k$). Btw you haven't replaced *all* indices $i$ yet.

Comment: Absolutely, $k-k$ is a typo for $k-j$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Try to see it in $\omega$'s

Let $\omega \in (X_1=j \cap X_1+X_2=k)$. Then

$$X_1(\omega)=j \cap X_1(\omega)+X_2(\omega)=k)$$

Now, $X_1(\omega), X_2(\omega)$ are just real numbers. Would you doubt that

$$a=j \wedge a+b=k \to b=k-j$$

?

You can also try to see it in indicator functions.

$$P(X_i=j \cap X_1+X_2=k)=E[1_{X_i=j \cap X_1+X_2=k}]$$

$$=E[1_{X_i=j \cap j+X_2=k}]$$

$$=E[1_{X_i=j \cap X_2=k-j}]$$

$$=E[1_{X_i=j}1_{X_2=k-j}]$$

$$=E[1_{X_i=j}]E[1_{X_2=k-j}]$$